# kineticjs doesn't display special characters such as â ä

Tags: html, special-characters, kineticjs

I'm unable to display special characters in canvas using kinetic.text.
The special characters are such as:  `â ä`
I'm able to display Devanagari Unicode characters, but not these characters.
I have saved the file in UTF-8 no signature mode.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

I had this meta header in html file that was causing the problem:

**<meta charset="UTF-8">**

Removing the line solved the issue.